# The Package Conflicts With An Existing Package By The Same Name Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, apk

I'm installing the flutter apk in android but not able to install it. as i'm fresher in flutter not able to get rid from this issue.

Apk install in other devices and working fine, only face this issue in my device.

Help me out to this!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. uninstall the old apk with the same name you installed before, then try once to install the app.
2. Same package error:

   1. Create a new Package in your app with a different name.
   2. Copy and paste all files in your old package to the new Package.
   3. Save Code.
   4. Delete the old Package And Clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to install or side-load an APK file on your Android device, this error occurs. When you try to install the same application's new APK, most of the time it fails because your phone already has the same application installed. As a result, the most obvious solution is to uninstall the app and then try to install the new APK. For the most part, this fix works.

Comment: this is not proper solution it should be update.